# Elixir warning: default arguments are never used

Tags: elixir

I have the following Elixir function:

```
defp prod(a, b\\0) do
    a*b
end
```

On compiling, I get the warning:

```
warning: default arguments in prod/2 are never used
```

Why does it think the default value won't be used?

Edit: here's the gist, if you want to take a look at the whole thing https://gist.github.com/findjashua/2ed4204247d76849eb81

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It will warn you that the default arguments aren't used if you never call `prod` with a single argument in that module. I'm assuming somewhere you are calling prod with `prod(someA, someB)`, but never `prod(someA)`.

Comment: i see, that makes complete sense actually. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also greatly appreciate it if you could tell me whether I'm writing idiomatic Elixir (added link to the Gist in the question)

Comment: The code looks idiomatic. You may also want to take a look at protocols as an alternative to the solution you have on the gist (and compare them!).